# How can we verify user by taking in explicit username and password input directly

Tags: android

I was wondering, how can we possible verify user, by taking in explicit username and password input directly. As I look into [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html), I do not see any function which accepts direct username and password. (I guess this is due to security reason)

The reason I'm asking so, as I wish to implement **Forget pattern** feature, on the top of this [Pattern lock screen](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/) library. Currently, the library doesn't provide such functionality.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shluld create an app specific passwork or link to an account on your server, but there is no way to check that credentials are correct, and if that would be possible, Google would immediatly fix it!

Comment: @Waza_Be Thanks. Do you have any suggestion, how we can help the users, just in case they forget their pattern? The lock pattern will be used in individual application wide.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng : I suggest you follow the lessons in this training article http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/index.html - you can use OAuth to obtain a token and verify it against Google servers.

Comment: @Squonk Currently, using OAuth, the best I can get is an external intent : http://i.imgur.com/10uURiX.png I still figure out no way for you to define your own UI controls, collect username + password, pass it to the API.

Comment: Seriously? If you want to collect username and pasword and if it work, it will be fixed ASAP, collecting credentials is a big flaw for Google and they will fight against that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can learn other popular app locker is that, there are several good ways to perform password recovery.

### Through email

[image]

### Through Q&A

[image]